# Find missing rows in SQL Server by criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to locate which Rows are not present between two paramatised dates.

For example (01/01/2010 and 01/01/2011)

```
ID      Date    col 3   col 4
123     01/01/2010  x   x
456     01/01/2010  x   x
6578    01/01/2010  x   x
123     01/03/2010  x   x
456     01/03/2010  x   x
6578        01/03/2010  x   x
123     01/01/2011  x   x
456     01/01/2011  x   x
789     01/01/2011  x   x
123     01/01/2012  x   x
456     01/01/2012  x   x
789     01/01/2012  x   x
```

I would like to return :

```
ID      Date    col 3   col 4
6578    01/01/2010  x   x
789     01/01/2011  x   x
```

So in pseudo-code

```
If Id exists for 01/01/2010 but not 01/01/2011, return result
AND
If Id exists for 01/01/2011 but not 01/01/2010, return result
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do.  The rows you returned are in your database above.  If you look at ID 456 and 789, the only difference is the ID.  Are you trying to return the row with the highest ID for each date?

Comment: What if there are other years, or other dates in those years?

Comment: I would like to be able to set the exact dates that the comparison is between.

Comment: @jedd . . . I think you should ask another question, and do a better job of explaining what you want.

Comment: It was clear in my head :) I think it's clear now I have edited!

Comment: huh, You adding more different data now

Answer (score 1):

First your logic wasn't sure. Try this now. Here is the [fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/46de0/1)

```
;with cte as
(
  select id 
  from t
  group by id
  having count(id) = 1
)
select t.id, t.date, t.col3, t.col4
from t join cte on t.id = cte.id

--Results
ID      DATE           COL3 COL4
789     2011-01-01      x   x
6578    2010-01-01      x   x
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for rows that appear only once, then this will work:

```
select *
from (select t.*,
             count(*) over (partition by id) as NumYears
      from t
     ) t
where NumYears = 1
```

Perhaps the more general form is:

```
select *
from t
where t.id in (select id
               from t
               group by id
               having (max(case when year(date) = 2010 then 1 else 0 end) = 1 and
                       max(case when year(date) = 2011 then 1 else 0 end) = 0
                      ) or
                      (max(case when year(date) = 2010 then 1 else 0 end) = 0 and
                       max(case when year(date) = 2011 then 1 else 0 end) = 1
                      )
               )
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon...but this doesn't work for my 'clearer' example

Comment: How did it not work?  There was an extra parentheses, but after removing it, the query does what you want.